# Wix install copy files

Tags: wix

I am working in wix installs. 
I am facing some problem while upgrading wix installs from one version to another version. My scenario like below.

I have installed my product x.1 and it have  sample folder in install folder but I want copy my sample folder files into backup while upgrading my installs.

But my problem is files are removing in upgrade before creating backup.

Please any one help.

Advance thanks
Uma

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing built in to backup files, but this is the gernal approach to do that:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2008/10/19/9006538.aspx

A thought: why do you need to do that? A major upgrade is a full install of an entire product (not simply the files you want to update) and it happens to uninstall an older version if there is one, so just include the sample files in the new setup.